# Pass windows variable to gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Is it possible that I can create a variable via a batch file and pass it to a Gitlab CI variable?

The background is that I want to declare the link of an environment:

```
environment:
    name: staging
    url: https://staging.example.com
```

a part of the URL results dynamically from the current build date. How can I pass the variable declared in a batch file to the gitlab-ci "url" variable?

The Url would look like this in the batch file:

> https://testme.com/Tool_%date:~-2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.zip

Outcome is:

> https://testme.com/Tool_180410.zip

and that variable i want to write in the environment URL variable

Answer (score 0):

I don't think creating a variable in a batch file and passing it to a GitLab CI variable is possible, but from what I've gathered from your scenario you could:

- set the current build date before you call the batch script
- pass in the variable to the batch script
- use the variable for your URL generation

For example (running on a Windows runner):

```
$ set testDate=%date:~-2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%
$ echo %testDate%
180410
# Use %testDate% wherever else you need it now for the rest of your build.
```

With regards to the Environment URL, I don't have any experience using it - but this [open issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/27921) could be of interest.

Comment: Hi, the content of the% testDate% variable somehow needs to be in the environment "url" variable of gitlab. Is there no way?

Comment: Looking at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#dynamic-environments `The name and url parameters can use any of the defined CI variables, including predefined, secure variables and .gitlab-ci.yml variables. You however cannot use variables defined under script.` - if you set the date variable in a before_script it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I usually set any variable needed in Gitlab's .gitlab-ci.yml in another separate yml file. Let's assume that the name of this second file is "parameters.yml", just to give an example.

You can create the parameters.yml file from your batch and define all your variables there.

Example of what parameters.yml contains:

```
 variables:
    name: staging
    url: https://staging.example.com
    [other variables]
```

Then, all you have to do is to include this yml into the "main" one (.gitlab-ci.yml), for example, something like this:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - release
  - deploy

include: parameters.yml
```

And that's it, now you will "see" all the variables defined in "parameters.yml"